# trying to write a query that returns data from two tables that have similar columns and value

Tags: mysql

I am new at MySQL and I am trying to write a query that will extract data from two tables,
that have two similar columns and if there values are the equal, it will give me the name of the students(other column).

this is what I wrote :

```
SELECT city(column) 
from cities, students(tables) 
where if city.cities = city.students 
return name.students
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but you should really read up a bit on how SQL queries are structured before moving further.

Comment: you are not mean i said that i am just starting it's ok ...

Comment: can you give a good place to start read or maybe a good learning site like codeacademy ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT students.StudentName --or how the column is called
FROM cities INNER JOIN students ON cities.city = students.city
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please read mysql docs - it'l be very helpful for you.

Second, try

```
SELECT cities.city, students.city
  FROM cities, students
 WHERE cities.city = students.city
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ! can you give a good web site to read about mysql and even practice it ? like code academy